# Multiline string to spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i would like to convert a multiline string to a spark dataframe,
what is the best way ?

```
val s =
      """
        |col1,col2,col3
        |a,b,c
        |u,v,w
      """.stripMargin
```

My current method: I write the string to a csv file and i read the csv file with the sparkSession. This is obviously not the best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val u = s.split("\n").drop(1).toSeq.map(_.split(",")).map(x => (x(0),x(1),x(2))).toDF("col1","col2","col3")

u.show()

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|
|   u|   v|   w|
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but include an explanation what this code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality and more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

That can be achieved by splitting the string into a sequence and then defining the dataframe on the sequence.

```
scala> """
     |         |col1,col2,col3
     |         |a,b,c
     |         |u,v,w
     |       """.stripMargin.split("\n").toSeq.toDF.show
+--------------+
|         value|
+--------------+
|              |
|col1,col2,col3|
|         a,b,c|
|         u,v,w|
|              |
+--------------+
```