# Apache Spark Ingest Custom Text File to DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I want to ingest data into apache spark however data is not in any of the supported format i.e CSV, JSON etc.

We have custom format where one record is present in the block of multiple lines.

Example

**Header --- Indicates start of record 1- Line 1
Header attribute - Line 2
Header attribute - Line 2

Payload - Line 3
Payload Attribute - Line 4
Payload Attribute - Line 5

Header --- Indicates start of record 2- Line 7
Header attribute - Line 8
Header attribute - Line 9

Payload - Line 10
Payload Attribute - Line 11
Payload Attribute - Line 12**

... So on

- There is no indicator to tell end of the record block.
- A new record can be identified by only start of new header
- Header indicator are ENUM

I want to ingest and convert the record in dataframe or RDD whichever is possible

Tried couple of forums
[Multiline string to spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617507/multiline-string-to-spark-dataframe)
and google search
however could not find any such example.

Comment: You could write a custom data source reader and use it ??